# Best & cheapest small hot water heater for condo?

Tags: water-heater

I live, part time, in a condo built in 2002. I have a short, squat 50-gallon water heater that is situated under my laundry counter top, that has worked just fine, despite being about 19 years old. I just got notice from condo board that because some folks had issues with theirs, we are all REQUIRED to replace said water heaters. I'm angry to have this added expense, because in googling prices, it looks like most hwhs this size are about $500! Can anyone recommend a good, cheap model? Thanks.

Comment: Google will usually find most prices in your area.  Condo can maybe get a better price buying in bulk instead of each owner buying their own.

Comment: I didn't thank of that, thanks!

Comment: Water heaters **do** wear out. 19 years is a decent lifetime for a residential water heater. Leaks in a condo affect others, unlike in a single-family home. "Shopping questions are off-topic." That being said, if you provide *specific details* we may be able to help guide you: Gas or electric? Dimensions (height, width, depth) of available space? The big cost is often the installation (same for 40 or 50 or 80).

Comment: Will probably need a plumber to remove and install also, do not think you can do it yourself without going against rules, but check.

Comment: Measure the space with care, and go looking on home improvement store and plumbing webstore sites for options being sure to factor in shipping from the places without local stores. Hardware stores (other than the Borg and the blue borg) can order you one, as well. The "style"' is "lowboy" as best I recall (I bought one last year, but that might not be the best deal for your particular situation.) Beware of prioritizing first cost over running cost (differences in running cost with electric heaters are pretty much differences in insulation) as running cost will get you for the next 20 years.

Comment: Quick search (orange) shows $500 is the starting point. Can go up a **lot** depending on features. Plus installation (which will be water + either gas or electric).

Comment: Cheapest?   Remember, often cheap is expensive and expensive is cheap.

Answer (score 1):

New water heaters will be larger in dimension, due to new efficiency rules which require a larger insulation jacket.

You may need to sacrifice some gallon capacity to get the dimensions you need.